# CSS3 transition, if parent class is changed

Tags: css, opacity, transition

I have a sticky header. The sticky stuff is made by a parent wordpress theme, so I don't want to alter the js-file, as it can get overwritten on the next update.

The js adds a class ".sticky" to the header. I want my logo to appear, when the header is sticky. And it should have a transition for the opacity value. The problem is, the following CSS does not work.

```
#logo {
    opacity:0;
    .transition(); /* This is LESS, the transition works well on other elements */
}

.sticky #logo {
    opacity:1;
}
```

The opacity changes, but the transition is not visible. If I try the same thing with :hover, like that:

```
#logo:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

everything works fine. Is there a pure CSS way, to get that to work?

Edit: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/7CmVF/3/) is a live example (updated)
      This works for me, even in firefox.

Edit 2: [Here](http://dev.regensburgerturmtheater.de/) you can find the real site, currently in development. The CSS looks the way it does in Zeaklous fiddle, but the outcome is different.
For some reason this does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `transition:opacity 1s linear;` or something similar?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Delay, too.

Comment: Can you provide a live example then?

Comment: I will try, that will take a bit time.

Comment: It seems to work for me. What's the issue?

Comment: It seems, that it works in a few browsers. The transition is visible in my IE, but not in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Then add browser prefixes for the transition: `-moz-transition`, `-webkit-transition`, `-ms-transition`, `-o-transition`, `transition`. [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/7CmVF/3/)

Comment: Now the fiddle works for me, but not the real site. There seems to be no difference. The logo is not a direct child of .sticky, but in the fiddle that makes no difference. I played around the whole morning. I think, I will have to move it from localhost to the web.

Comment: Done. I made the primary content very long, so the sticky header can be tested.

Comment: The fiddle works for me in the latest stable Chrome (29). Seems to be the known bug of Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=800927

Comment: I don't think it is. As I said, the fiddle now works for me, the live site does not. The position-value changes (in both cases) for the whole header, but not for the logo itself.

Comment: Did you solve this eventually?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I do, I will post it here.